# My datagridview cant be passing to another form textbox

Tags: c#

I want move the data to another form but the textbox there have error.i adry try it many time

[image]

```
payment pym = new payment();           
pym.textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
pym.textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
pym.textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
pym.textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
pym.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: 'payment.textBox6' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: is `payment` in your first line code a  form?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i=0;
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value == null || (txttotal.Text == ""))
            {
                string message = "Please select the product payment detail and calculate the total Sum";
                string title = "Error payment process";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title);
                button1.Enabled = true; 
            }
            else
            {
                SetValueForText1 = txttotal.Text;
               (The error code here)
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it into payment form

```
public void GetText4(string txt) => textBox4.Text = txt;
```

and call it into you form:

```
payment pym = new payment();  
pym.GetText4(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
pym.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: ok Done Thanks.

Comment: nice, then mark it as answer :)